# color of sky from an airplane

Tags: visible-light, scattering

My textbook says that the sky appears black to the passengers of an airplane flying at a high altitude.They further explain it by saying that this is because of the fact that the atmosphere of that region is not dense enough to scatter light,and hence the sky is black.

But according to me light is scattered in all directions at the lower part of the atmosphere.

So,should the plane passenger not be able to see the blue scattered light around him ,coming from the bottom(since scattering takes place at the region below the plane) ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sky+seen+from+aeroplane+at+high+altitude&tbm=isch

Comment: "light is scattered in all directions at the lower part of the atmosphere.". There you go, you answered it yourself. The light is scattered in all directions, including up.

Comment: Of course if you look down you see the Earth with its atmosphere around.

Comment: @seejianshin yes then is my textbook wrong?as through this reasoning the sky should be blue as scattering takes place in all directions

Comment: No neither of you are wrong. From the pictures you can see that the upper part of the sky is black because of little scattering. The lower part of the sky is blue because of more scattering.

Comment: The blue sky scattering that you see below you will not be visible when you look up because there is very little in that direction to reflect the blue back to your eye, The blue scattering is there, but it is not being reflected back to you. It travels away from Earth into parts beyond.